# Grouping a pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes with 1 year intervals starting from every cell and then storing them in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a dataframe with stock prices of an index, and the day at which I got these prices. Let's say the data is for two years. It looks like this:

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2002-01-01 | 278.95 |
| 2002-01-03 | 278.75 |

I want to create multiple dataframes where I can get a years worth of data starting every day. For example, I want 1 dataframe starting from 2002-01-01 to 2003-01-01, the next one to be 2002-01-02 to 2003-01-02. This will continue so on until the end. Basically if I have two years worth of data, I would get 365 separate dataframes if I had data for everyday in those 2 years.
Of course an issue is that the yearly data doesn't have a fixed number of rows as some days are missing, so i need to account for that too.

Any help would be appreciated!

I don't really understand how I can do this using Pandas. I have the following code but it just makes 1 year intervals, instead of making 1 year intervals starting from everyday day I specify.

`dfs = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='1Y'))]`

Comment: Why do you need one dataframe for each day? it seems like an overkill.

Comment: @snowman I want to get some summary statistics such as max price, and some other metrics in yearly intervals starting from each day, and then I would create a starting date and a new dataframe with all my metrics. I believe this isn't the most efficient solution but I didn't think too much about it. I'd love to hear about suggestions on how I can make it more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta
dataframes = []
for date in data.date.unique():
    dataframes.append(data[data.date.between(date,date+timedelta(365))])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?